# If object is Generic List

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, list, generics

Is there any way to determine if an object is a generic list? I'm not going to know the type of the list, I just know it's a list. How can I determine that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This will return "True"

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();

Console.Write(myList.GetType().IsGenericType && myList is IEnumerable);
```

Do you care to know if it's exactly a "List"... or are you ok with it being IEnumerable, and Generic?

Comment: This doesn't currently compile.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/T0Q8w3. Maybe it did in '08.

Comment: Hey @sonicblis, "IEnumerable" is in the namespace "System.Collections". You didn't have a `using System.Collections;` in your fiddle. Still compiles in 2016 :)

Answer (score 7):

The following method will return the item type of a generic collection type.
If the type does not implement ICollection<> then null is returned.

```
static Type GetGenericCollectionItemType(Type type)
{
    if (type.IsGenericType)
    {
        var args = type.GetGenericArguments();
        if (args.Length == 1 &&
            typeof(ICollection<>).MakeGenericType(args).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            return args[0];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Edit:** The above solution assumes that the specified type has a generic parameter of its own. This will not work for types that implement ICollection<> with a hard coded generic parameter, for example:

```
class PersonCollection : List<Person> {}
```

Here is a new implementation that will handle this case.

```
static Type GetGenericCollectionItemType(Type type)
{
    return type.GetInterfaces()
        .Where(face => face.IsGenericType &&
                       face.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
        .Select(face => face.GetGenericArguments()[0])
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer doesn't guarantee the type of IList<>.
Check this version, it works for me:

```
private static bool IsList(object value)
{
    var type = value.GetType();
    var targetType = typeof (IList<>);
    return type.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType 
                                      && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == targetType);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if(yourList.GetType().IsGenericType)
{
  var genericTypeParams = yourList.GetType().GetGenericArguments;
  //do something interesting with the types..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is ambiguous.

The answer depends on what you mean by a generic list.

- A List<SomeType> ?
- A class that derives from List<SomeType> ?
- A class that implements IList<SomeType> (in which case an array can be considered to be a generic list - e.g. int[] implements IList<int>)?
- A class that is generic and implements IEnumerable (this is the test proposed in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248903/if-object-is-generic-list#248918))?  But this will also consider the following rather pathological class to be a generic list:

.

```
public class MyClass<T> : IEnumerable
{
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The best solution (e.g. whether to use GetType, IsAssignableFrom, etc) will depend on what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

Theres a GetType() function in the System.Object class. Have you tried that?

Comment: Event though maybe this is not a "perfect" answer, I cannot see why it is flagged minus one. Come on guys, it's not the best possible answer but try to not damage somebody's reputation.

Comment: GetType will return the specific generic list that it is, as opposed to the fact that it is just a generic list.