# Casting to a generic of any type in C#

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have an `object value` that might represent objects of different types (string, enums, List etc). What I want to do is check whether the variable is an empty list, like this:

```
(value is List<object> && ((List<object>)value).Count == 0)
```

or

```
(value is List<dynamic> && ((List<dynamic>)value).Count == 0)
```

But with real empty lists both return false.
I'd like to know what's the best way to do this, and if there's something like Java's `List<?>` in C#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If object is Generic List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248903/if-object-is-generic-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast it to [`IList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if( (value as IList).Count == 0 )
```

If you are not sure whether the value implements `IList`, it is better to check for null:

```
var list = value as IList;
if(list != null && list.Count == 0)
```

Comment: @GeneMarin `using System.Collections;`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper class:

```
public static class CollectionHelpers
{
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this ICollection collection)
    {
        return collection == null || collection.Count == 0;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        Console.WriteLine((list as ICollection).IsNullOrEmpty());
    }
}
```

or

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<int>();
        Console.WriteLine(list.IsNullOrEmpty());
    }
}
```