# How to find the member type of a list

Tags: c#, list, types

So far I have this:

```
if (o.GetType().IsGenericType && o is System.Collections.IEnumerable)
        {
            var typefield = typeof(List<object>).GetFields().Where(f => f.Name == "T").ToArray();
            Type T = (Type)(typefield[0].GetValue(o));
            addButton.Enabled = true;
            if (((System.Collections.IList)o).Count > 0)
            {
                removeButton.Enabled = true;
            }
            comboBox1.Enabled = true;
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();

            foreach (var item in Assembly.GetAssembly(T).GetTypes().Where(x => T.IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsAbstract))
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";   
        }
```

but it crashes on the line "Type T = (Type)(typefield[0].GetValue(o));" because the array is empty, which means that the previous line did not work.

**Question:**
Assuming that everything that passes the first line is a List, how should I determine the type of objects in the list. (note that checking the type of the members is not good enough. The members are likely to be derived from the Type that is specified in the list definition.)

**P.S.**
I read here that my first line is the best way to determine something as a list:
[If object is Generic List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248903/if-object-is-generic-list)
Do you have a more accurate way?

Comment: may be it should be typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable)?

Comment: how about `(o.GetType().IsGenericType && o is IList)`

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you looking for `o.GetType().GetGenericArguments()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one answer could be this method:

```
public IEnumerable<Type> GetGenericIEnumerables(object o) {
    return o.GetType()
            .GetInterfaces()
            .Where(t => t.IsGenericType == true
                && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
            .Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments()[0])
            .ToList();
}
```

The you can use it this way:

```
var type= GetGenericIEnumerables(o).FirstOrDefault();
```

If o is is not `IEnumerable<T>`, then the type is null, else, it returns `T`.

It also works perfect when o is not generic itself, and inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`, for example for `string` the function will return `char`.

Based on [jason's asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/906513/3110834).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you get the generic parameters via

```
Type.GetGenericArguments()
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To determine the type of a `List<T>` you can use `Type.GetGenericArguments()`

```
var o = new List<int>();

if (o.GetType().IsGenericType && o is IList)
{
    var args = o.GetType().GetGenericArguments()

    if(args.Count() == 1)
    {
        Type T = args[0];

        // rest of code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetGenericArguments`. This code will give you the type of element in your list `o`

```
if (o.GetType().IsGenericType && o is System.Collections.IEnumerable)
{
    var itemType = o.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    //Console.WriteLine(itemType);
}
```

If you have

```
var o = new List<string>{ "a", "b" };
```

It will give you

```
System.String;
```