# Convert a Model Class Collection to Dictionary based on property as KEY using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary, model

I'm having a collection of Person `List<Person>`, now I need to create a Dictionary, the **Key should be a Property Name** and the **Values are Distinct Values of that respected Property** i.e., `List<Object>`

The Dictionary should be like `Dictionary<string, List<object>>`

C# Source Code:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Person> EmpList = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person() {ID = 101, Name = "Peter", Gender = "Male", Role = "Manager"},
        new Person() {ID = 102, Name = "Emma Watson", Gender = "Female", Role = "Assistant"},
        new Person() {ID = 103, Name = "Kaliya", Gender = "Manager", Role = "Assistant"},
    };
}

public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

My Expectation is

```
Dictionary<string, List<object>> EmpDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();
EmpDictionary.Add("ID", new List<object>() { 101, 102, 103 });
EmpDictionary.Add("Name", new List<object>() { "Peter", "Emma Watson", "Kaliya" });
EmpDictionary.Add("Gender", new List<object>() { "Male", "Female" });
EmpDictionary.Add("Role", new List<object>() { "Manager", "Assistant" });
```

I wish to construct a Dictionary as like this using LINQ C#

> Note: Give solution as global. There should be a **n** Number of
>   Properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var d = typeof(Person).GetProperties()
                      .Select(p => new
                      {
                          Key = p.Name,
                          Value = EmpList.Select(epm => p.GetValue(epm)).ToList()
                      })
                      .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... If the List is a Item Source, then we don't know the typeof collection. Then how to achieve this? kindly assist me...

Comment: You may find this post helpful: [How to find the member type of a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32822141/3110834)

Comment: Why do you pass the name and values through an anonymous type? Why not just pass them to `ToDictionary` directly and avoid synthesizing those?

Answer (score 1):

This won't be the most performant option (you've already got that), but it would function.

```
var ret = typeof(Person)
    .GetProperties()
    .ToDictionary(c => c.Name, c => EmpList.Select(x => c.GetValue(x)).ToList());
```

I'd be a bit tempted to reconsider what you're doing, admittedly. Unless you're specifically trying to play around with reflection and LINQ together (in which case, rock on!), I'm not sure this will be a good design for most cases. Just food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Person>();

dictionary.Add("101", new Person{ Id = 101, Name = "Peter" ... etc...}
```

you can then address this dictionary much more easily:

```
Console.WriteLine("Name: " + dictionary["101"].Name);
```

Comment: I can achieve this using EmpList.ToDictionary(x => x.ID); But my requirement is different. Kindly read the post once again please...

Comment: You should rethink your code. Make objects that make sense to YOU and other colleagues. Instead of trying to be "smart" in code, you should avoid doing the "not so smart" things, like reducing the readability of your code. If you have a set of person objects, treat it like that, and not as a set of weird properties that you will spend 15 minutes understanding what you did 3 months from now.

Comment: I'm creating a Custom DataGrid, for that I need the Column wise Distinct Values for filtering operations. So, I need as like that...